# XenServer -Virtual Disk not Active

Tags: storage, xenserver

What ever i am trying add as virtual disk (i.e. usb disk, local drive). It is showing 'Active = no' under the storage tab

Screenshot:

[image]

Running fdisk -l it shows only the disk where the OS is installed.

I am using XenServer 7.2

Any help?

Comment: Any chance you tried to reboot the XenServer to see if the disk show up in fdisk -l?

Comment: Nope. I have restarted several times but not getting anything using fdisk -l.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your screenshot the two fields `device path = unknown` and `active = no` could indicated that `drive 1` and `drive 2` had been previously used in XenServer system and for some reason never get purged correctly.

According to a similar post, a possible solution could be to setup your disk from an highest number (4, 5, 6...) and proceed to a complete shutdown of the system (rather than reboot).

http://www.destinationip.com/index.php/site/xencenter_virtual_disk_device_path_unknown1/